# Why are the arrows of the 3d quiver plot pointing the wrong way?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, simulation, physics

I have been working on modeling magnetic fields for research. The code below allows me to calculate correct values of the field for any given point *(x,y,z)*; however, when I pass a `np.meshgrid` object through the code, the results start to get wonky.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d


def normal_vector(u):
    return u/np.linalg.norm(u)
class Path:
    """
    This defines the Path class which allows for the calculations of the magnetic field.
    """

    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs):
        self.points = zip(*[xs, ys, zs])  # defines the points
        self.x = xs
        self.y = ys
        self.z = zs
        self.path_vectors = [(self.points[i + 1][0] - self.points[i][0],
                              self.points[i + 1][1] - self.points[i][1],
                              self.points[i + 1][2] - self.points[i][2]) for i in range(len(self.x) - 1)]
    def get_length(self):
        """
        Calculates the path length
        :return: returns float length
        """
        return sum([np.sqrt(((self.x[i + 1] - self.x[i]) ** 2) + ((self.y[i + 1] - self.y[i]) ** 2) + (
                (self.z[i + 1] - self.z[i]) ** 2)) for i in
                    range(len(self.x) - 1)])

    def get_magnetlic_function(self,axes,current=1.0,magnetic_constant = 1.25663706212e-6):
        magnetic_parameter = (current*magnetic_constant)/(4*np.pi)
        field_function = lambda x,y,z: sum([magnetic_parameter*np.cross(self.path_vectors[j],normal_vector(np.stack([x-self.x[j],y-self.y[j],z-self.z[j]],axis=-1)))/(np.linalg.norm(np.stack([x-self.x[j],y-self.y[j],z-self.z[j]],axis=-1))**2) for j in range(len(self.x)-1)]).swapaxes(0,-1)
        return field_function

n = 200
r = 1
h = 5
grid_x,grid_y,grid_z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10,10,5),
                    np.linspace(-10,10,5),
                    np.linspace(-10,10,5))
c = h / (2 * n * np.pi)
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 5000)
xp = 3*np.cos(t)
yp = 3*np.sin(t)
zp = 0*t
p = Path(list(xp), list(yp), list(zp))
func = p.get_magnetlic_function([grid_x,grid_y,grid_z])
u,v,w = func(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z)
r = np.sqrt(u**2+v**2+w**2)
print func(-10.0,00.0,0.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax1.plot(xp,yp,zp,'r-')
ax1.plot([-10],[0],[0],'ro')
ax1.quiver(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z,u/r,v/r,w/r,length=1)
plt.show()
```

As is clear near the bottom, if the code is run, the direction of the vector at -10.0,00.0,0.0 is not the same as the value that gets printed. Why? 
From the code, I recieve the quiver plot here:
[image: My code.]

It should look like:
[image]

Comment: Is my answer more what you are looking for? Would it be better if I included a demonstration of how to use your `lambda` function correctly with `np.meshgrid`?

Comment: The answer is great! Thanks for the help! Turns out that numpy arrays get pretty wonky in the lambda function. If you have some time, I'd love to see your implementation with lambda as well though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to find the magnetic field caused by a current distribution I find it is often much clearer to consider pairwise interactions (although the `lambda` function is far more pythonic). Consider this approach

```py
class Path:
    # ...
    def mag_func(self, x, y, z, current = 1.0, mag_const = 1.25663706212e-6):
        mag_param = current * mag_const / (4 * np.pi)
        s = x.shape
        res = np.zeros((s[0],s[1],s[2],3))
        for i in range(s[0]):
            for j in range(s[1]):
                for k in range(s[2]):
                    for idx, (xc, yc, zc) in enumerate(zip(self.x, self.y, self.z)):
                        res[i,j,k,:] += mag_param * \
                                np.cross(self.path_vectors[idx], [x[i,j,k] - xc,
                                         y[i,j,k] - yc, z[i,j,k] - zc]) / \
                                np.linalg.norm([x[i,j,k] - xc, y[i,j,k] - yc, 
                                              z[i,j,k] - zc])**2
        return res[:,:,:,0], res[:,:,:,1], res[:,:,:,2]
#...
u, v, w = p.mag_func(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z)
r = np.sqrt(u**2+v**2+w**2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax1.plot(xp, yp, zp, 'r-')
ax1.quiver(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, u/r, v/r, w/r,length=1)
plt.show()
```

Which will give

[image]

Which is the correct representation of the magnetic field surrounding a current carrying wire.

As for the question of why the `lambda` doesn't work in the first place, I think it is due to the creation of the grid via `np.meshgrid` such that the outer `sum` was summing over more points than it should have been. Iterating in the way above remedies that issue. It would be possible to use that `lambda` function but I think you would have still have to iterate over the `grid_x`, `grid_y`, and `grid_z` in the manner shown.